# How to prove that the following two sets are equal?

Tags: functional-equations

Let $M=\{x|f(x)=x\},~N=\{x|f(f(x))=x\}$, and $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$, where $a,b\in R$ are such that $4b=(a-1)^2$. Show that $M=N$.

Comment: if $f(x) = x$ then $f(f(x)) = f(x) = x$

Answer (score 2):

Proceed to show the desired result by showing $M\subseteq N$ and $N\subseteq M$. The first part follows easily since
\begin{align}
&x\in M \Rightarrow f(x)=x \\
&\Rightarrow f(f(x))=f(x)=x\\
&\Rightarrow x\in N.
\end{align}

Thus, $M\subseteq N$. In order to show that $N\subseteq M$, consider an $x$ such that $f(f(x))=x$. Then, we have
\begin{align}
x-f(x)=f(f(x))-f(x)&=(f(x))^{2}+a(f(x))+b-(x^{2}+ax+b)\\
            &=(f(x)-x)(f(x)+x+a). 
\end{align}

This implies that 
\begin{eqnarray}
(f(x)-x)(f(x)+x+a+1)=0.
\end{eqnarray}

From here, we conclude that the only possibility is $f(x)=x$, since if $f(x)=-x-a-1$, then $f(f(x))\neq x$. Thus, we have shown that if $x\in N$, then $x\in M$, which implies $N\subseteq M$.

Hence, $M=N$.